# how can i get the latest record published by each singer

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

table 1 : `songs`

```
-songname varchar
-singerlabel varchar
-date date                            
-category varchar
```

table 2 : `singer`

```
-singerlabel varchar
-singer#  varchar
```

table 3 : `singerNote`

```
-singer# varchar
-firstname varchar
-lastname  varchar
```

table 1 is connected to table 2 using `singerlabel`.

table 2 is connected to table 3 using `singer#`.

Comment: Aren't you missing a column named `singer#` in table `songs` ?

Comment: there is no relationship between singer and songs.

Comment: Corrected it, please have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query:

```
select singerlabel, max(date) maxdate
from songs
group by singerlabel
```

you get the max date of each `singerlabel`, and then `join` to the other 3 tables:

```
select sn.firstname, sn.lastname, songs.songname
from (
  select singerlabel, max(date) maxdate
  from songs
  group by singerlabel
) s inner join singer
on singer.singerlabel = s.singerlabel
inner join singernote sn
on sn.singer = singer.singer 
inner join songs
on songs.singerlabel = s.singerlabel and songs.date = s.maxdate
```

Comment: Can it also be done without using inner or outer join ? I mean using an uncorrelated query

Comment: This would be less efficient.

Comment: it is for a small database

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports window functions, this can be achieved with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        si.*, sn.first_name, sn.last_name, so.songname, so.date, so.category
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY so.singerlabel ORDER BY so.date DESC) rn
    FROM singer si
    INNER JOIN singerNote sn ON sn.singer#     = si.singer#
    INNER JOIN songs      so ON so.singerlabel = si.singerlabel
) x WHERE x.rn = 1
```

---

Without window function, you can use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to ensure that you are joining with the most recent song :

```
SELECT si.*, sn.first_name, sn.last_name, so.songname, so.date, so.category
FROM 
    singer si
    INNER JOIN singerNote sn 
        ON sn.singer# = si.singer#
    INNER JOIN songs so 
        ON so.singerlabel = si.singerlabel
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM songs so1
            WHERE so1.singerlabel = si.singerlabel AND so1.date > so.date
        )
```